# Limit the number of event loops

Tags: vert.x, vertx3

In [vertx docs](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/) they mentioned there is a possibility to limit the number of event loop threads per vertx instance:

> Instead of a single event loop, each Vertx instance maintains several event loops. By default we choose the number based on the number of available cores on the machine, but this can be overridden.

Maybe someone knows how to do that? (I need it for debugging purpose)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setEventLoopPoolSize(1));
```

By default it's:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_POOL_SIZE = 2 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 This is pretty handy when you want to check if concurrency is the cause of any problems (and all server-side Java problems are concurrency problems).